# difference between input and feature transform in pointnet?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

[pointnet architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ayX.jpg)

i am currently reading this paper , in which the raw point-cloud co-ordinates are undergoing two transforms , input-transform and feature transform , the transform itself is made of a mini-pointnet followed by a matrix multiply , the input transform transformed it into a nx3 vector , where as the feature transform transforms it into an nx64 vector .
however both the transforms are essentially same in structure (tnet x matrixmultiply) , then how can we say that the first transform transforms the input and the second one acts on features?

Comment: Point cloud is an important type of geometric data structure. The classification network takes n points as input, applies input and feature transformations, and then aggregates point features by max pooling. The output is classification score for m classes. The segmentation network is an extension to the classification net.

Comment: i know that much , but the input and feature transforms are both similar in structure , so how can we say that they perform that particular transforms.(nx3-->input transform , nx64 --> feature transform)

Comment: see, the feature transform network is a replica of the input transform method in [pointnet architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ayX.jpg), submodule is used to predict the feature transformation matrix. However, unlike the input transformation network, the feature transformation network takes 64 dimensional points.

Comment: the input transform acts on the data such that the network becomes invariant to permutation of points , feature transforms makes the network robust to rigid geometrical transform , but both are similar in structure

Comment: yes, both are in the similar structure. Transformations add background experience to the input data, enabling the machine learning model to benefit from this experience. Do you understand about the classification network, transformation network and segmentation network on [pointnet architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ayX.jpg)

Comment: once you get a vector representation of the point cloud from the transormer network classification network, transformation network and segmentation network act on the obtained vector , just like replacing the last layer of a convnet with bounded box , softmax etc ,

Comment: but , in the paper they have suggested the "transform" to make the point cloud invariant  , see appendix which implies the "input transform" but they have used the same for "feature transform" as well by just changing the dimension to 64 , which i dont understand ,

Comment: So, you are not clear about the transformation matrix in [pointnet architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ayX.jpg), You want to know the process of transformation matrix & geometric transformation in  [pointnet architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ayX.jpg). If it is correct, then I will explain.

Comment: the whole T-net matrix multiply appears black box to me

Comment: The input to the segmentation network consists of the set of transformed point features (in this case n×64 features) concatenated by the global feature extracted by the classification network using the max pooling operation. Finally, they jointly learn an alignment network on the input points as well as on the feature points (n×3 input and n×64 features in pointnet architechture).

Comment: @thecomplexitytheorist have you learned anything new about Tnet that you could share? Also for me the Tnet appears like a blackbox.

Comment: @Elia I have implemented the whole thing from scratch , it took me quite a while to get an idea of what each block does . Also the proof , if possible i will make a small presentation an will send it to you.

Comment: @thecomplexitytheorist that is great work, and I would appreciate anything that could help clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but in the hope that someone finds this answer useful, my understanding is:

Both transformations consist of a T-net that outputs a matrix, which is then performs an [affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) when multiplied by the point cloud, aligning all the point clouds to the same input or feature space. The T-net is composed of all the modules that come after the feature transformation in the PointNet classification architecture. A shared MLP, max pooling and another MLP.

The input transformation aligns all the different point clouds to a [canonical space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490342/what-is-meant-by-canonical), effectively centring the point cloud around the origin and scaling it so that all the point clouds the network trains from are a standardised size.

The feature transform then performs the same operation, now using point clouds that have been embedded using a shared MLP to the feature space. This is shared MLP is key as it means the output has an understanding of all the points in a given point cloud and are embedded to a feature space. The 64xn representation of the point cloud can all then be aligned to the same feature space. As the shared MLP trains on all the point clouds, it will embed to a more robust feature space representation of the point clouds.

An understanding of [word embedding](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-the-heck-is-word-embedding-b30f67f01c81) really helped me to understand how PointNet and similar point cloud architectures work as embedding the point clouds to the feature space is very similar.

[image: PointNet Architecture]

Comment: Why not using data augmentation instead of T-Net? E.g. random rotations, translations etc.